# Running Selenoid Grid and getting periodic ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED on Browser open

Tags: robotframework, selenoid

We are running Selenoid Grid on a three node cluster (that is also running Kubernetes).  Every so often when running some robotframework tests the same test in Chrome browser on the grid we see ERR_NETWORK_CHANGED when we open browser page and test fails.  We never see this when not running in Grid.

Captured tcpdump and saw (RST, ACK) coming from docker container for chrome browser.  Would appreciate any suggestions on how to debug this.

And yes, we do plan on moving the Grid to its own nodes (as there could be conflict between Kubernetes and Selenoid as we are not running the Kubernetes version).

Comment: Could be unstable DNS issue.